# Compute Engine - Automatic scale

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have one VM Compute Engine to host simple apps. My apps is growing and the number of users too.
Now my users work basicaly from 08:00 AM to 07:00 PM, in this period the usage os CPU and Memory is High and the speed of work is very important.
I'm preparing to expand the memory and processor in the next days, but i search a more scalable and cost efective way.
Is there a way for automatic add resources when i need and reduce after no more need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cost of running your VMs is directly related to a number of different factors i.e. the type of network in use (premium vs standard), the machine type, the boot disk image you use (premium vs open-source images) and the region/zone where your workloads are running, among other things.

Your use case seems to fit managed instance groups (MIGs). With MIGs you essentially configure a template for VMs that share the same attributes. During the configuration of your MIG, you will be able to specify the CPU/memory limit beyond which the MIG autoscaler will kick off. When your CPU/memory reading goes below that threshold, MIG scales your VMs down to the number of instances specified in your template.
You can also use requests per second as a threshold for autoscaling and I would recommend you explore the docs to know more about it.

[See docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler)